# Building QScintilla on Windows fails

Tags: makefile, qmake, qscintilla

I was able to build the most recent version of QScintilla (2.9.1) on Ubuntu 15.10. I have tried building the same version on Windows 10 using Qt 5.6. QMake run to completion without giving errors. A call to Make gives the following error message:

```
make -f Makefile.Release
make[1]: Entering directory 'G:/Sources/QScintilla/QScintilla_gpl-2.9.2/Qt4Qt5'
Makefile.Release:822: *** missing separator.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory 'G:/Sources/QScintilla/QScintilla_gpl-2.9.2/Qt4Qt5'
makefile:34: recipe for target 'release' failed
make: *** [release] Error 2
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I solve it?

Comment: When building on Windows, "missing separator. Stop."  usually means that you are using a "*nix" version of make instead of a Windows aware version of make.  On my Win7 machine, I use `mingw32-make` if I am building for mingw.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issues. I eventually got a working 'QScintilla' on my Windows 10 machine as described below.

My PC has the following specifications:

- Windows 10, 64-bit OS
- Anaconda package installed (Python 3.5)
- PyQt5 installed (download the `.exe` installer from https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5)

---

**STEP 1:**

Download the file `QScintilla-2.9.2-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl` from the site https://pypi.python.org/pypi/QScintilla .
Put the file in the folder:

> C: \ .. \ Anaconda \ Scripts \

We will use this `.whl` file to do the installation of QScintilla.

_

**STEP 2:**

Open the Windows `cmd` tool with Administrator privileges! Now type the following command:

```
> cd "C:\..\Anaconda\Scripts"
```

This brings the `cmd` shell to the right spot. Now type the following command:

```
> pip3 install QScintilla
```

If all goes well, you get the following message:

```
> pip3 install QScintilla

    Collecting QScintilla
      Downloading QScintilla-2.9.2-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl (1.6MB)
        100% |################################| 1.6MB 984kB/s
    Collecting PyQt5 (from QScintilla)
      Downloading PyQt5-5.6-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl (74.7MB)
        100% |################################| 74.7MB 23kB/s
    Collecting sip (from PyQt5->QScintilla)
      Downloading sip-4.18-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl (46kB)
        100% |################################| 51kB 5.7MB/s
    Installing collected packages: sip, PyQt5, QScintilla
    ..
    Successfully installed PyQt5-5.6 QScintilla-2.9.2 sip-4.18
```

_

**STEP 3:**

I did not get the message "Successfully installed" from the first shot. Instead I got the following error message:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\..\anaconda\Lib\site-packages\sip.pyd'
```

Apparently the file `sip.pyd` sitting in the directory `C:\..\anaconda\Lib\site-packages` could not be accessed. So I opened another Windows command shell (of course again with Administrator privileges!) and typed the following command:

```
> icacls "C:\..\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages" /grant "Administrators":(OI)(CI)F /T
```

This command will give full access rights (read - modify and write) to all "Administrator" users for all the files in the `site-packages` folder, and all the files in its subfolders. While this command executes, you should get the following messages:

```
    ...
    processed file: C:\..\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\__pycache__\readline.cpython-35.pyc
    processed file: C:\..\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\__pycache__\simplegeneric.cpython-35.pyc
    processed file: C:\..\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\__pycache__\six.cpython-35.pyc
    processed file: C:\..\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\__pycache__\test_path.cpython-35.pyc
    processed file: C:\..\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\__pycache__\test_pycosat.cpython-35.pyc
    ...

    Successfully processed 38589 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

Now you can repeat STEP 2, and it should work!